# Send video file to save on android phone using C program

Tags: android, c, video

Using C program, I want to send a video file to my android mobile and save (or download) it on the phone.

Right now I have made an android app from which I can send messages/text to C server. (using socket programming)
And i want my C server to send video back to my android phone(client)  when it receive the message "send video"

Guide me please. How can I achieve this ? Any related links would be appreciated...
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one article which can help you to achieve what you are looking for-

[Java and C socket communication](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/java-and-c-socket-communication/222900697)

I have worked on it once(long time back). They are using a Java client here, you can use your Android app. It's a brilliant article.